# On Azure Portal :-Can we create MAC OS virtual Machine, I am unable to find MAC OS on it

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

On Azure Portal :-Can we create MAC OS virtual Machine, I am unable to find MAC OS on it. if Yes please share the name of OS available on portal with screenshot

Comment: It's an unplanned feature.https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/13826655-mac-os-x-virtual-machines

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to create a MacOS Virtual Machine in Azure. You can only create VMs with Windows or Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is nothing like this on Azure.
Please refer this link from Azure Admin:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/13826655-mac-os-x-virtual-machines

Comment: Link is dead now. Alternative/migrated post [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/931fcbc4-c225-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c)